# Google Maps API v3 Places Autocomplete PostCodes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm trying to configure this to only suggest postcodes but I cannot figure out how.
I have managed to filter to show only in a single country and can get it to work showing cities only, but not with postcodes. I am unsure that it even supported. Is it?

This is what I'm using at the moment:

```
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), { types: ['geocode'], componentRestrictions: { country: ['uk'] } });
```